# Quote about being better not to give something than to take away

Tags: quote-source, james-clavell

I'm looking for source of a quote about being better not to give something than to take away. It's been many years, so I can't recall much more about the quote. I thought it would be from the book Shogun by James Clavell. It was oriented around a king deciding whether to reward princes and the idea that being a miser is better than giving something and then potentially needing to take it back later... Unfortunately, google searches aren't super helpful -- too many unrelated hits.

This also seems like something that Machiavelli would have said.

Comment: But this is common knowledge, via the cautionary tale we’ve all heard about the way the sale of a pound of candy is executed: by putting too much on the scale, and then removing until the right weight is reached (resulting is a depressed customer), or putting too little on the scale...